# Is there a rails or rack gem that blocks hacked URL requests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, scanning

My Rails application frequently receives bogus traffic from hackers scanning for vulnerabilities, hitting URLs like `/vb/showthread.php%3C/a`. These show up as noise in our logs and I would like to filter them out or handle these in some way (such as alerting someone to the scanning attempts).

Is there a Rails or Rack gem that already does this, or are there similar libraries in other frameworks that do the same thing?

Comment: fair enough...I never asked a question like this before. voted to close.

Comment: @max you are right about this question but chastising me is not really a very friendly way to remind someone about the rules. This is the sort of comment that makes people say that the SO community is unfriendly.

Comment: Sorry, bad day.

Comment: @max thx apology accepted

Comment: I went through the guidelines again and I don't understand why it is not on-topic. @KenLiu do you know why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [rack-attack](https://github.com/kickstarter/rack-attack) middleware gem is general enough to block requests based on any attribute of a request, and provides other advanced features for handling malicious traffic, such as request throttling, blocklists, and request logging.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this really answer your question by I think a custom filter will be better instead of a general gem.

I've added a before filter on my applicaton_controller to handle weird request, then you can alert and do what you want.

```
class ApplicationController < ....
  before_action :filter_hacks #first filter

private
  def filter_hacks
    if request.format.to_s == 'php'
      #do something: email, save report, anything
      head(:ok) and return false
    elsif #add other filters

    end
  end
```

I'm sure it could be improved, but you have full control of what you want to block and what to do when that happens.

Answer (score 0):

This is a great use case for middleware. You can store a list of known bad routes and use whatever logic you'd like to intercept and handle the request before it makes it through to your app. I would read up more on how to use Rack middleware in the [Rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/rails_on_rack.html).

But it could be accomplished with something similar to this:

```
class FilterBadRequest
  BAD_PATHS = [
    "/vb/showthread.php%3C/a"
  ]

  def initialize(app)
    @app = app
  end

  def call(env)
    req = Rack::Request.new(env)

    bad_request = BAD_PATHS.find { |bad_path| req.fullpath ~= bad_path }

    if bad_request
      raise ActionController::BadRequest
    else
      @app.call(env)
    end
  end
end
```

This raises an `ActionController::BadRequest` exception, but you can redirect or do whatever else makes sense within the context of your application. You'll need to make sure to register the middleware within your application config file inside the `config` block like by calling `config.middleware.use FilterBadRequest`